# Kubernetes ingress-nginx metrics uri label

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress, metrics, ingress-nginx

How to get a label of uri that was used for a request.
For example, I made a request `curl https://www.somesite.com/api/health`

I see on Prometheus labels:

`host` [www.somesite.com](http://www.somesite.com)
`path` / (ingress is configured with path "/")

How can I see metrics over "/api/health"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.